# React Native bug - Trying to send command to a non-existing view with tag 203

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I don't know why this is popping up, I just copy my codes from my other Project and compare it, perfectly the same but I still got this bug.

Is there anyone that encounter bug like this? I don't know maybe there is any wrong configuration about my Environment?

My Environment:

```
"expo": "^35.0.0",
"expo-constants": "~7.0.0",
"expo-location": "^7.0.0",
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-dom": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "1.3.0",
"react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
"react-native-maps": "^0.26.1",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
"react-native-screens": "^1.0.0-alpha.23",
"react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
"react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
"react-navigation-animated-switch": "^0.3.2",
"react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
"react-navigation-tabs": "^2.6.2",
"react-redux": "^7.1.3",
"redux": "^4.0.4"
```

My Code for Parent Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View, StatusBar} from 'react-native';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import {Constants} from 'react-native-unimodules';

import EventItem from '../../components/EventItem';

const HeaderComponent = () => {
return (
    <Text style={styles.header}>Events</Text>
);
}

const EventsOverviewScreen = props => {
const events = useSelector(state => state.events.events);
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor='transparent' translucent barStyle='light-content'/>
        <FlatList
            data={events}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            ListHeaderComponent={HeaderComponent}
            ListHeaderComponentStyle={styles.headerContainer}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            renderItem={itemData => (
                <EventItem
                    image={itemData.item.imageUrl}
                    title={itemData.item.title}
                    description={itemData.item.description}
                    onViewDetail={() => {
                        props.navigation.navigate('EventDetail', {
                            eventId: itemData.item.id
                        });
                    }}
                />
            )}
        />
    </View>
);
};
```

My Child Component:

```
const EventItem = props => {
let TouchableCmp = TouchableOpacity;

if (Platform.OS === 'android' && Platform.Version >= 21) {
    TouchableCmp = TouchableNativeFeedback;
}
return (
    <View style={styles.eventContainer}>
        <View style={styles.event}>
            <View style={styles.touchable}>
                <TouchableCmp onPress={props.onViewDetail} useForeground>
                    <ImageBackground source={{uri: props.image}} style={styles.image}>
                        <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                            <Text style={styles.title}>{props.title}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.description}>{props.description}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </ImageBackground>
                </TouchableCmp>
            </View>
        </View>
    </View>
);  
};
```

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same

Comment: Same problem after installing react-native-paper and I think after focusing an Input element

Comment: Same problem here, any fixes?